# Gradle munges directory names while creating a jar with all dependencies

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

This is my task:

```
task uberJar(dependsOn: [classes], type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from { 
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'cli'
    }
}
```

It's a very simple project, one that just builds a single groovy script into a self-contained, executable jar file. I know the Groovy code works. When I tried to run `java -jar` on the generated jar file, it said it could not find a file that I knew was included. So I expanded the jar file and found that several packages had been munged. This is the folder structure I found:

[image]

Any idea why it is doing this? This task is based on a common one that I find all over the place for how to build a jar with all of the dependencies using Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jar contents look correct. Most if not all of the top-level directories depicted come from `groovy-all`, which apparently is a dependency of your code. A JVM won't load classes from nested Jars (`change-password.jar`) unless a custom class loader is used.

Using class names that don't start with an upper-case letter (`cli`) can lead to problems in Groovy. More importantly, merging Jars isn't generally safe and can lead to subtle problems. A better way to create a self-contained executable Jar is to use the [gradle-one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) plugin.

PS: Instead of the first two `from` lines, `from sourceSets.main.output` should be used. Then the explicit `dependsOn` (which by the way is missing `processResources`, which would explain missing *resource* files) can also be removed. If you don't need the regular Jar, you can reconfigure the `jar` task rather than adding an `uberJar` task. (If you go for this, omit `from sourceSets.main.output`.)